# Prevent malicious scripts to be submitted in post

Tags: forms, scripts

I am building a wordpress backed web application where users will submit posts. Is there any way to prevent malicious codes from being submitted (by way of hooks or filters)?

Comment: can't you use moderation?

Comment: Other than sanitising? I don't think there's enough information here about your system, e.g. is WP inserting the posts or are you doing it via SQL queries? There's no code in your question

Comment: Define mailicious codes

Comment: @Tom J Nowell it's a private journal app where users post text using wp rest api.

Comment: @kero Cross Site Scripting

Comment: Sanitize incoming data https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php